# angluarjs trigger $http on model update

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I am building a TODO-lists app using *Angularjs*, *nodejs* and *mongoose*.
What I want to do is to trigger ajax when watched model changes.

I noticed the well known todomvc use the following code

```
$scope.$watch('todos', function () {
    $scope.remainingCount = filterFilter(todos, {
        completed: false
    }).length;
    $scope.doneCount = todos.length - $scope.remainingCount;
    $scope.allChecked = !$scope.remainingCount;
    todoStorage.put(todos);
}, true);
```

However I have a TODO detail panel, and I use x-editable to in-place edit the title.
The model is  referenced by `app.currentTodo`.

Currently I use

```
$scope.$watch('currentTodo', function(){ $http... });
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle or plunker?

Comment: I tried ngResource, then $watch a "resource object"(deep value compare)  and $save it.
However, the "resource object" has $save, $update attributes, which will impact the comparasion ( $watch will compare every attribute, even $save, $update which is appended by a Q promise)

http://plnkr.co/edit/pnlubalVXCtdNMucjI9J?p=preview

I am frustrated and want abandon Angularjs and seek for Backbone etc.
Can you shad some light on it, and make my Angluar way ?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/pnlubalVXCtdNMucjI9J?p=preview